# Duplicate Entries During Batch Call Procedure

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a stored procedure that basically looks like this:

```
do_insert (IN in_x varchar(64), IN in_y varchar(64))
BEGIN
                declare v_x int(20) unsigned default -1;
                declare v_y int(20) unsigned default -1;

                select x into v_x from xs where x_col = in_x;

                if v_x = 0
                then
                    insert into xs (x_col) values(in_x);
                    select x into v_x from xs where x_col = in_x;
                end if;

                select y into v_y from ys where y_col = in_y;

                if v_y = 0
                then
                    insert into ys (y_col) values(in_y);
                    select y into v_y from ys where y_col = in_y;
                end if;

                insert ignore into unique_table (xId, yId) values(v_x, v_y);
END
```

Basically I look to see if I already have the varchars defined in their respective tables, and if so I select the id. If not, then I create them and get their IDs. Then I insert them into the `unique_table` ignoring if they're already there. (Yes I could probably put more logic in there to NOT have to do the final insert, but that shouldn't be an issue and KISS.)

The problem I have is that when I run this in a batch JDBC statement using Google Cloud SQL I get duplicate entries inserted into my `xs` table. The next time this stored proc is run I get the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Result consisted of more than one row Query: call do_insert(:x, :y)
```

So what I think is happening is that two calls with the same `in_x` values are occurring in the same batch statement. These two calls are being run in parallel, both selects come back with 0 as it's a new entry, then they both do an insert. The next run then fails.

Questions:

- How do I prevent this?
- Should I wrap my select (and possible insert) calls in a `LOCK TABLE` for that table to prevent this?
- I've never noticed this on a local MySQL, is this Google Cloud SQL specific? Or just a fluke that I haven't seen it on my local MySQL?

Comment: OK, so I tried adding locks and got the error: `ERROR 1314 (0A000): LOCK is not allowed in stored procedures` So now what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this yet, but I'm guessing the batch statement is introducing some level of parallelism. So the 'select x into v_x' statement can race with the 'insert into vx' statement allowing the latter to be executed more than once.

Try changing the 'insert into xs' statement to an 'insert ignore' and add a unique index on the column.

Comment: That's a pretty slick work-around for this. Maybe not even a work-around as it's leveraging the constraints functionality that RDBs provides.